# Angularjs - My App does't work on safari browser

Tags: angularjs

Hello I have an issue when I run my code on safari browser 
and here are error logs

[image]

[image]

I think this problem in $cookies 
if you have any solution, please help me to solve it.

Comment: You should probably include **versions** of AngularJS, ngCookies, and Safari browser that you are using

Comment: And maybe some of your code...

Comment: do you mean I need to update angularjs version?

Comment: @AdelSadek we mean that nobody can help you unless we see your code. Do you have the same errors on other browsers? Is their version more recent than Safari? Old browsers and angularjs modules may behave differently

Comment: @AlekseySolovey no my code work well in any browser except safari

Comment: @AlekseySolovey in my project there are many files and i don't know which file is !!

Comment: @AdelSadek once again, post your scripts and safari versions. It's not just the code that broke, you can't get CKEditor through SSL

Comment: @AdelSadek your Safari version should be at least 11 to support ES6 syntax. Safari 6.1.6 supports only TLS 1.0 (and not SSL)

Comment: Windows Safari Not support Angular. try  Mac safari version 11+